# Property grid only show some category

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I got a PropertyGrid that is use on an object that have the following property category : Style, Calcul and Misc

What I want is to only show to the user the Calcul category, but I don't want to use the browsable attribute because I want all these property to be visible in Visual studio.

So, what I need, is an in-code solution.

I use .Net 3.5 c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PropertyGrid` has a property - `BrowsableAttributes`; assign this your categories:

```
        propGrid.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(
            new CategoryAttribute("Calcul"));
```

And (hopefully) it should work.