# C#: PropertyGrid Only Show 2+ Categories via BrowsableAttributes

Tags: c#, user-interface, attributes

The same question than [Property grid only show some category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706871/property-grid-only-show-some-category) but showing multiple categories instead of only 1.

I have 3 categories: All, Red, Blue.

I want to show All and Red categories in the PropertyGrid.

I try :

`myPropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new CategoryAttribute("All"), new CategoryAttribute("Red"));`

but nothing is displayed. If I only put 1 CategoryAttribute it works fine though but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Most people would say that you are incorrectly implementing the property grid if you are requiring this level of manipulation. The property grid can be abused and attributes assigned to make your GUI simple to develop but for other people using your code or end product, a defined purpose oriented GUI is probably a better choice. I know this isn't the answer you wanted, but its the truth.

If you must use the property grid, I often write a wrapper that only exposes the properties I want shown on the property grid. This helps prevent a change in my code from breaking my end user GUI.

**Obviously, this example can be accomplished with `[Browsable(false)]` but I'm making this simple to demonstrate the concept.**

I have

```
class Vector4
{
    property float X {get;set;}
    property float Y {get;set;}
    property float Z {get;set;}
    property float W {get;set;}
}
```

but don't want the property W to be visible in the property grid. Make a wrapper like

```
class Vector4Wrapper
{
    Vector4 refVector;

    property float X 
    {
        get{ return refVector.X; }
        set{ refVector.X = value; }
    }
    property float Y 
    {
        get{ return refVector.Y; }
        set{ refVector.Y = value; }
    }
    property float Z 
    {
        get{ return refVector.Z; }
        set{ refVector.Z = value; }
    }

    Vector4Wrapper(Vector4 refVector)
    {
        refVector = refVector;
    }
}
```

Finally, use the wrapper by saying something like this to expose only the properties you want:

```
Vector4 vect;
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = new Vector4Wrapper(vect);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue:

The problem is that if you supply multiple values to `BrowsableAttributes`, the `PropertyGrid` will only display properties that have ALL of those attributes. So if you provide two different categories, it will only display properties that are in both categories. The CategoryAttribute doesn't allow you to specify more than one category, so this will not work.

I managed to get around this by creating my own custom attribute class.

See:
[Disabling items in PropertyGrid using Custom Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761295/disabling-items-in-propertygrid-using-custom-attributes)