# Disabling items in PropertyGrid using Custom Attributes

Tags: .net, custom-attributes, propertygrid

I am able to selectively enable / disable items in a `PropertyGrid` by setting `BrowsableAttributes` to an array containing `CategoryAttribute` objects. However, I wish to enable some items within a category and disable others within the same category, so I thought I would create my own custom attribute class and apply this to the properties in my object, but this does not seem to work.

Here is my custom attribute class:

```
Public Enum HeadType
    DMA = 1
    TMA = 2
    Both = 0
End Enum
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class HeadTypeAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
    Public Property HeadType As HeadType
    Public Sub New(HeadType As HeadType)
        Me.HeadType = HeadType
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function Match(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Debug.Print("HeadTypeAttribute.Match obj.HeadType=" & obj.HeadType.ToString())
        Debug.Print("HeadTypeAttribute.Match Me.HeadType=" & Me.HeadType.ToString())
        Dim bMatch As Boolean = TypeOf obj Is HeadTypeAttribute AndAlso CType(obj, HeadTypeAttribute).HeadType = Me.HeadType
        Debug.Print(bMatch)
        Return bMatch
    End Function
End Class
```

I set `BrowsableAttibutes` to an array containing two instances of my HeadTypeAttribute class, one with HeadType = HeadType.Both and one set to either HeadType.DMA or HeadType.TMA. I can see that the Match method is being called and is returning true for some items, but the grid is always empty.

Comment: A bit of experimenting, and it seems there may be nothing wrong with the custom attribute class. It's just that if you set multiple values in BrowsableAttributes, the properties then have to have ALL not ANY of those attributes in order to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not adding the Both item in BrowsableAttributes and changing the Match function to always return True when the Both value is encountered seems to fix it:

```
Public Overrides Function Match(obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return TypeOf obj Is HeadTypeAttribute AndAlso (CType(obj, HeadTypeAttribute).HeadType = Me.HeadType OrElse CType(obj, HeadTypeAttribute).HeadType = HeadType.Both)
End Function
```